# Materials do not show in material preview mode

Tags: materials

[image]I'm kinda new to blender so don't know a lot, but I apply a material to my object I can't see it in material preview mode. It seems to just show a grey highlight. I've done some searching and my driver is up to date and I have the latest version of blender. I have a Radeon RX 560 graphics card. I just have no idea why I can't see my materials. Any help is appreciated thanks.

This is what it looks like in material preview mode.

Comment: If you have an AMD GPU, it's the latest Adrenalin drivers causing it. To fix, you can either roll back your drivers to an earlier version, or try enabling "High Quality Normals" under _Render Properties > Performance_

Comment: Hi, thanks man enabling High-Quality normals solved the issue.